# How do I get the text that user is typing in GooglePlacesAutocomplete?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm working on a project where I'm using Google autocomplete.

```
const SuggestionRow = ({ item }) => (
  <View style={{}}>
    <View style={{}}></View>
    <Text style={{}}>{item.description}</Text>
  </View>
);
const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;

export default function MapSearch({ setLocation }) {
  let predefined = [];

  const placesRef = useRef();

  return (
    <View style={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH, paddingHorizontal: 5 }}>
      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        placeholder="Search"
        onPress={(data, details) => {
          setLocation(details);
        }}
        minLength={4}
        fetchDetails
        styles={{
          textInput: styles.textInput,
        }}
        query={{
          key: "",
          language: "en",
        }}
        predefinedPlaces={predefined}
        suppressDefaultStyles
        ref={placesRef}
        renderRow={(item) => <SuggestionRow item={item} />}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I need to be able to get what the user is typing as he/she is typing. I've been trying to do this with useRef(), but it's not updating when I type in the screen. I've tried doing this using a useEffect:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState()
useEffect(() => {
  setInputValue(placesRef.current?.getAddressText())
})
console.log('inputValue',inputValue)
```

but I'm not getting a value or update in my console. I've also tried using useCallback():

```
const placesRef = useCallback(node => {
  if (node?.current?.length > 0) {
    setInputValue(node.current?.getAddressText();
  }
}, []);
```

but that didn't work either for me. I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just use the `onPress` event or other similar events?

Comment: It seems like a better approach would be to make your component a controlled component. You would do this by using the `useState` hook. You would then update the state using an event listener on the user input component. Can you set the `onChange` attribute on the input component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes to a `ref` object do not cause a re-render, so `placesRef.current?.getAddressText()` returns the information when called, but it's never called because the component is not re-rendered.

Pass an object to the `textInputProps` (see [docs](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete#props)) property of the `GooglePlacesAutocomplete`, and pass `setInputValue` as the [`onChangeText`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext) handler to update the state when the text changes in the `TextInput`:

```
textInputProps={{
  onChangeText: setInputValue
}}
```

Example:

```
export default function MapSearch ({setLocation}) {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState();
  
  let predefined = [];

  const placesRef = useRef();

  return (
  <View style={{width:SCREEN_WIDTH, paddingHorizontal:5}}>
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      textInputProps={{
        onChangeText: setInputValue
      }}
      placeholder='Search'
      onPress={(data, details) => {
       setLocation(details)
      }}
      minLength={4}
      fetchDetails
      styles={{
        textInput: styles.textInput,
      }}
      query={{
        key: '',
        language: 'en'
      }}
      predefinedPlaces={predefined}
      suppressDefaultStyles
      ref={placesRef}
      renderRow={(item) => <SuggestionRow item={item} />}
    />
  </View>
  )
}
```